# Prove the following with Induction

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

$$\sum_{j=0}^d (s-1)^j \le s^d $$ for all $ s \ge 1 $ and $ d \ge 0 $, where $ s$ and $d$ both are natural numbers.

I have been trying to do this with induction for a while, I have also tried to use the geometric addition formula:

$$\sum_{j=0}^d s^j = \frac{s^{d+1}-1}{s-1} $$

I tried holding $d$ constant and doing Induction on $s$, I also tried the opposite, holding $s$ constant and doing induction on $d$. But it seems I can't solve the problem.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

In the question $ 0^0 $ is defined as $1$. The below answer should not be taken into consideration.

Comment: Write $s^d$ as $((s-1)+(1))^d$ and expand by the Binomial Theorem. Now the result is obvious by term by term comparsion.    Or you could use $(s-1)^r \leq \frac{d!}{r!(d-r)!}(s-1)^r$ for $0 \leq r \leq d $

Comment: $$\sum_{j = 0}^{d+1} (s-1)^j = 1 + (s-1)\sum_{j = 0}^d (s-1)^j$$